# Having trouble using JSoup to obtain list of artists + tracks from HipHopEarly website

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm starting to become frustrated with this little project of mine. What's weird is I had the program working at one point. I came back to add a little bit more to the program, and it no longer grabs anything. I'm assuming the website changed a tad?

I'll apologize in advance if I'm just making a stupid mistake, as I'm still new to programming.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class scraper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "http://www.hiphopearly.com/tracks";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements tracks = doc.select("#left-column div.tracklisting div.tracks div.track");
        for (Element track : tracks) {
            System.out.println(track.text());
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program, nothing is returned. I'm fairly positive that the problem lies with the content within:

```
doc.select("#left-column div.tracklisting div.tracks div.track");
```

How can I determine the correct CSS path to grab the artist and track titles?
I tried copy and pasting the CSS path given automatically by the Chrome browser, but had no luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as follows:

```
String url = "http://www.hiphopearly.com/tracks";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0")
    .get();

Elements tracks = doc.select("#left-column div.track-listing div.tracks div.track");
for (Element track : tracks) {
    System.out.println(track.text());
}
```

This case is quite often - website generates different content based on the clients useragent. [Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo) was almost right - it would be the case he mentioned if you will get the JavaScript template (e.g. AngularJS) in your browser as well (you can check it by showing the source of the website, not Firebug which displays rendered result).

The second thing is that tracklisting class have changed to "track-listing".